# OAuth 2.0 {"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."} in Postman

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, postman, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to execute a REST API call in SharePoint Online. For this, I wanted to see if I can register an app in Azure AD. I believe I was able to do so and I'm able to get back a token. However, upon executing the GET request Postman always throws `{"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}`in the body of the response.

Here're the screenshots detailing everything:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Don't mind the Postman variable {{TenantID}}. That's not the issue, I also tried with the writte-out tenant ID - doesn't make a difference.

So what I was unsure about at first was the 'Scope' parameter in the "GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN" in Postman. I tried various scopes, for example 
'Sites.FullControl.All' or 'https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/.default'. But that didn't change the outcome. Still, is the scope I set correct for SharePoint REST API? I know that for the Microsoft Graph 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' works.

I also tried different app permissions, not just 
'Sites.FullControl.All'

Do you have any idea what the cause of the error might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sharepoint permission `Sites.FullControl.All` is of type **Application**.
For this type of permission you MUST use the [client_credential](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/) flow.

> The Client Credentials grant is used when applications request an
>   access token to access their own resources, not on behalf of a user.

Try to call the auth url with:

```
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Otherwise if you want to access the Sharepoint on **behalf of the user** change the permission type to **delegated**

Comment: Thanks. In the *GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN* window of Postman I changed the grant type to *client credentials*. Now I'm getting the error message `{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}` I can't figure out what's wrong. I even recreated the app registration in Azure. Is the scope of `https://{{TenantID}}.sharepoint.com/.default` correct? It won't let me not specify a scope. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can't edit the last comment. Wanted to add that I switched the API permission type from application to delegated and set the grant type back to *Authorization Code* but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: According to this [stackexchange post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/220642/oauth-authentication-for-sharepoint-rest-api) it seems that the url is incorrect. Try with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/tenantname.sharepoint.com/lists`